# How do I make an application with 0 libraries with lua?

Tags: lua

I'm trying to work from scratch and make a game using 0 libraries. I can't find any place to document how to make the application part, (i.e; mouse properties, drawing stuff, etc) mostly because they are drowned out with stuff for LOVE2D and other things.

If that made no sense, how would I replicate drawing a box like done in LOVE2D using no libraries in a terminal?

I've asked some professional programmers I know and they don't have the experience with lua to know how its done, but gave me pointers on how I can do things efficiently once I can actually make and draw on an application window.

Comment: Fancy stuff like application windows are normally done using Lua's [C API](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#4). You will still have to use whatever C library that allows you to interface with your GUI environment.

Comment: A "drawing stuff" is OS-dependent, so you need access to OS functions, either via some library or by accessing OS functions directly using FFI.  Lua standard library has only `io.read` and `io.write` for simplest work with console.

Answer (score 0):

Wrong direction @Connor Fricke
Lua is an 'extensible extension language'
And even with '0 libraries' you have some work to do.
A Technic so called: Sandboxing
I give you an example for luajit (using an extended Lua 5.1) and Lua Versions above 5.1 where the load() will accept the argument for the environment of loaded and executed code.
And even this example has to use `io` for input/output.
LuaJIT is also built in LÖVE and NeoVIM
Code

```
-- repl.lua -- Interpreting in sandboxed environment
--[[ Example for allowing math and debug
repl = require('repl')
repl({math = math, debug = debug})
]]
local function repl(libraries)
local prompt = 'Input' -- The Prompt is used for results
local out, inp = io.write, io.read -- Abbreviations
local sandbox = type(libraries) == 'table' and libraries or {} -- Environment for load()
local bool = false -- For pcall()

while prompt ~= '' do -- The Loop
    out(prompt .. '> ') -- Output
    prompt = inp() -- Input
    if prompt ~= '' then -- Interpret it
        bool, prompt = pcall(load, 'return ' .. prompt, 'REPL', 't', sandbox)
        prompt = bool and prompt() or 'FAILED' -- If bool is true then execute prompt
    else
        prompt = ('no input'):upper() -- In case we really get nothing back
    end
end
error(('%s'):format('No Input - EXIT'))
end

return(repl)
```

Example of use

```
€ luajit -e 'require("repl")()'
Input> 1+1
2> _VERSION
FAILED> jit.version
luajit: [string "REPL"]:1: attempt to index global 'jit' (a nil value)
stack traceback:
    [string "REPL"]:1: in function 'prompt'
    ./repl.lua:18: in function <./repl.lua:6>
    (command line):1: in main chunk
    [C]: at 0x565bd110
€ luajit -e 'require("repl")(_G)'
Input> _VERSION
Lua 5.1> jit.version
LuaJIT 2.1.0-beta3>
```

EDIT - Forgetting to wrote that to remove all string library functions from datatype string you have to do...

```
> _VERSION = debug.setmetatable(_VERSION, nil)
> _VERSION
Lua 5.4
> _VERSION:upper()
stdin:1: attempt to index a string value (global '_VERSION')
stack traceback:
    stdin:1: in main chunk
    [C]: in ?
```

...than my example repl.lua will also fail because it uses string methods for the prompt and error() formatting.